# jQuery Nice Select Overflowing Webpage Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [jQuery Nice Select](https://jqueryniceselect.hernansartorio.com/) to display a long list of **select options**, it seems to work but the problem is that the options are overflowing both the parent container and the entire web page.

[image: jQuery Nice Select Error Example]

Please how do I fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nice-select .list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 280px;
}
```